# How to parse string tree into array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, graph-theory

Let's say I get an API response that returns a tree-like structure like this:

```
"gw43g: (-95.147, 38.5818); " +
"jp987h: (" +
         "bvp7: (-97.450, 30.150); " +
         "7g8oi: (" +
                 "34ilht: (-82.192997, 29.39719); " +
                 "34hb1: (-122.25, 37.47)); " +
         "b238: (-71.0349, 42.2129)); " +
"ao8yh: (-90.147, 42.5818);"
```

Its a string.

Using JavaScript, I need to turn it into an array like this..

```
["(-95.147, 38.5818)",
  "(bvp7: (-97.450, 30.150); 7g8oi: (...)...)",
  "(-90.147, 42.5818)"]
```

..such that the innards of each pair of parenthesizes is an array item, no matter many nested parenthesizes are contained in the outermost pair.

I'm not having any luck, so I'm asking your your guy's help. Here's what I've tried.

```
function getCoords(str) {
    return str.split(';').map(function(s) {
        return s.substring(s.indexOf('(')+1, s.lastIndexOf(')'));
    });
}
```

..but that's way wrong. Feel free to call on any functional toolkits (underscore.js, etc). And no, this is not a homework assignment, it's for a book I'm writing. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a parser for this, but here's a quick and dirty solution that's kind of like a mini-parser:

```
var src = "gw43g: (-95.147, 38.5818) .... ";

var re = /(\w+:\s*\()|(\);?)|((?:(?!\w+:\s*\(|\);?).)+)/g;

var output = [];
var match;
var stackCount = 0;

while ((match = re.exec(src)))
{
    if (match[1]) {
        if (stackCount == 0) output.push('');
        stackCount++;
    }
    else if (match[2]) {
        stackCount--;
    }
    output[output.length-1] += match[0];
}
console.log(output);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w15r9f2b/)

The regular expression splits tokens into three categories, a stack opener, a stack closer, or neutral.  If it finds a stack starter and there is nothing on the stack it adds a new array item, if it finds a closer it brings the stack down by one.  Until the stack is at zero, it will keep appending to the current array item.

I couldn't help it, so I went ahead and just finished the simple parser, so that the string is output as an tree where the root properties are the keys (gw43g), and each either has an X, Y value, or it is a branch on the tree.

```
function parseBody(str) { 
    // rey: http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/fxd02f
    var re = /\s+|(\w+)\s*:\s*\(|(\);?)|(([\-+]?\s*(?:\d*\.\d*|\d+))\s*,\s*([\-+]?\s*(?:\d*\.\d*|\d+)))/g;

    var output = [];
    var match;
    var newObj;
    var root = { children: { } }
    var branch = root;

    while ((match = re.exec(str)))
    {
        // key and open
        if (match[1]) {
            newObj = { parent: branch, children: { } };
            branch.children[match[1]] = newObj;
            // new stack
            branch = newObj;
        }
        // 
        else if (match[2]) {
            // move up stack
            branch = branch.parent;
        }
        else if (match[3]) {
            branch.X = parseFloat(match[4]);
            branch.Y = parseFloat(match[5]);
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w15r9f2b/6/)

### [Regular Expression](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/fxd02f)

Comment: I really liked stewe's answer, and it solves your described problem concisely, but I went ahead and added to my answer a fully implemented parser so that you can get the data as object instead of an array of strings.  [*I really just wanted to get in your book :-)*]

Comment: Daniel, your answer is longer and I was hoping for something more "functional programming", HOWEVER it is 5x faster! I used JSLitmus to test, here's the results: http://tinyurl.com/nxxvafb ...I wish I could choose both as the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
var str = "gw43g: (-95.147, 38.5818); " +
"jp987h: (" +
  "bvp7: (-97.450, 30.150); " +
  "7g8oi: (" +
     "34ilht: (-82.192997, 29.39719); " +
     "34hb1: (-122.25, 37.47)); " +
  "b238: (-71.0349, 42.2129)); " +
"ao8yh: (-90.147, 42.5818);"

var cnt = 0; // keep count of opened brackets

var result = Array.prototype.reduce.call(str, function(prev, curr) {
  if (curr === '(' && cnt++ === 0) prev.push('');
  if (cnt > 0) prev[prev.length-1] += curr;
  if (curr === ')') cnt--;
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

[JSFiddle mirror](http://jsfiddle.net/jaar6be1/)

Comment: I'm a getting this right:  You're using the `Array.prototype.reduce` function on a string, so that it enumerates character by character like an array of char?  Very cool.

Comment: @DanielGimenez: exactly! Most array methods also work on 'array-like' objects like Strings. Have a look at: [Array-like objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like) and [Array generic methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods)

Comment: Seems like var result = str.split('').reduce((prev, curr) => { … }) would work as well?

Comment: Alternatively, you can call: `Array.from(str).reduce((prev, curr) => /* code */, [])`